# Karate 0.9.5.RC5 - 'retry until' function somehow does not respect my 'retry' configuration in karate-config.js

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, karate

I have following test:

```
Feature: News API

  Background:
    * url baseUrl

  Scenario: get news index
    Given path "/"
    And retry until responseStatus == 200
    When method get
    Then status 200
    And match response contains "News service up and running"
```

and the following karate-config.js

```js
function fn() {
    // get java system property 'karate.env'
    var env = karate.env;
    karate.log('karate.env system property was:', env);

    var config = {
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
    };

    karate.configure('retry', {count: 5, interval: 6000});
    karate.configure('connectTimeout', 5000);
    karate.configure('readTimeout', 5000);

    return config;
}
```

and the following error in the console after executing the tests with the maven-failsafe-plugin:

```
...
[INFO] Running newsservice.NewsServiceIT
[main] INFO  o.a.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8080: The target server failed to respond
[main] INFO  o.a.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8080
[main] INFO  o.a.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8080: The target server failed to respond
[main] INFO  o.a.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8080
[main] INFO  o.a.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8080: The target server failed to respond
[main] INFO  o.a.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec - Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8080
[main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:8080 failed to respond, http call failed after 2 milliseconds for URL: http://localhost:8080/
[main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed: 
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:8080 failed to respond
---------------------------------------------------------
feature: classpath:newsservice/news/news-index.feature
scenarios:  1 | passed:  0 | failed:  1 | time: 0.7678
---------------------------------------------------------

HTML report: (paste into browser to view) | Karate version: 0.9.5.RC5
...
```

Before the tests start, I boot up my Spring Boot application and this takes some time (~5-7 seconds) and I know that the test does not succeed because the Sprint Boot app has not yet started.

That's why I've tried to use this `retry until` feature of Karate to make sure it retries after some intervals.

But it seems that the `retry` config is not respected according to the console output. It seems so that it always only try 3 times...

I have also tried to set the `retry` config in the test file itself like in the Karate docs with:

`* configure retry = { count: 10, interval: 5000 }`

but this also did not work.

Maybe you have a hint why it does not work or do I still miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `retry until` comes into the picture only *after* the HTTP connection has been established. You need to figure out a way to wait until your server can accept connections.

Why you see 3 attempts is because that is the default behavior of the underlying Apache HTTP client.

You should be able to write or re-use some utility to do this. Take a look at this code from Karate internals, look for the `waitForHttp` method:

https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/v1.4.1/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/shell/Command.java#L219

And in my opinion, the best place to do this "wait" is in the JUnit / Java code that kicks off the Karate suite - which you probably already have for starting Spring Boot.